# Reach OData service from locally running SAPUI5 app

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-gateway

I am having a problem running an SAPUI5 application locally with Visual Studio Code. I am serving the webapp files with a static files server run by Grunt at localhost:8080
The problem is reaching the backend OData services. The first problem which was  a CORS error I have solved with using a reverse proxy which is run by NodeJS.

This is the code of the reverse proxy:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const https = require('https');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var backendHost = "YYY-XXX.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com";
var frontend = 'http://localhost:8080';
var fs = require('fs');

app.all("/sap/opu/*", function (req, res) {
  console.log("HOST:" + req.hostname + " URL: " + req.url);
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {
    changeOrigin: true,
    hostRewrite: false,
    followRedirects: true,   
    autoRewrite: true,
    protocolRewrite: true,    
    preserveHeaderKeyCase: true,
    xfwd:true,
    target: {
      hostname: backendHost,
      port: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: backendHost,
      agent: https.globalAgent,
      pfx: fs.readFileSync('F:\\Cert.pfx'),
      passphrase: 'XXX',     
    }
  });
});
app.all("*", function (req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: frontend });
});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

The code is running fine. When I enter in the browser localhost:3000 I get the web app files, but I can see that  requests made by the webapp towards the the SAP backend ("YYY-XXX.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com")  yields the following html response:

"Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.
Continue"

One more thing: Is there any test environment for the SAPUI5 app on SAP cloud platform? I can only see the "live" version which is the production code. Is there any staging environment?

I would appreciate any help because using Web IDE is not an option for me. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend using https://caddyserver.com/ for local hosting and reverse proxy, I use it all the time

Comment: How do you authenticate against the SAP backend?

Comment: Concerning your other question: We have 3 different sub accounts in the SCP, one for dev, one for test, one for prod.

Comment: @Mar: I have added my SAP passport to the request towards  the netweaver gateway with lines:
 pfx: fs.readFileSync('F:\\Cert.pfx'),
 passphrase: 'XXX',